# Explain insert query with select queries inside

Tags: mysql

I'm refactoring someone's code where queries like this are all over the place and I can't understand what's going on. I have no idea what to search for and "mysql insert with nested select" doesn't yield anything helpful.

```
INSERT INTO stats_users_hour (
        hour,
        uid,
        lastupdate,
        hash1hr
        )
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
          ? as hour, 
          ? as uid, 
          ? as lastupdate, 
          ? as hash1hr) AS tmp
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT lastupdate FROM stats_users_hour WHERE lastupdate = ? AND uid = ?
        ) LIMIT 1
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastupdate = ?, hash1hr = ?
```

I'm not even sure how to indent this properly. I'm assuming the first select uses the values yielded from the second select, but where does the second select get it's data from? Is this just an "update or create" query? And are the first select's results used as values for the insert query?

I'm sorry if this is duplicate. Any help is appreciated.

edit: Also the where clause, what query does it apply to? I assume the first select query but not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This create a Table with one row, which will be inserted, if soem conditions arrive see below

```
   SELECT 
      ? as hour, 
      ? as uid, 
      ? as lastupdate, 
      ? as hash1hr
```

this will check if such a row exsist already in the Table `stats_users_hour`  (same `pid` and `lastupdate` )

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT lastupdate FROM stats_users_hour WHERE lastupdate = ? AND uid = ?
    )
```

And when such row exists,, so that now new row will be inserted

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastupdate = ?, hash1hr = ?
```

This will update the row with the newest data for `lastupdate`  and `hash1hr`

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are awesome.